# How do I use jQuery to load a photo?

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery to display larger images in a window when a thumbnail is clicked. This aspect works very well. However, I have a series of windows and when I close out one window the main image does not load when I open a new window.

I am working on this page: http://ee.rouviere.com/web/portfolio

If you click on any one of the thumbnail images it pops up a window and you can click through the thumbnails. When you close out the window the jQuery clears the values. However, when you click on another thumbnail the main image does not load until you click on one of the thumbnails.

How do I get the main image to load when the window opens?

Here is the jQuery I am using. I began with this:

```
$("a:has(img.web-port)").click(function() {
    var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
    var caption = $(this).attr("title");
    $(".photo_large").attr({ src: largePath});
    $(".caption1").text(caption);
    return false;
});
```

That works great to trigger the larger images. But then I added this because the last main image would not load in the next window that I opened:

```
$("#fancybox-close").click(function(){
   $(".photo_large").attr({ src: ''});
   $(".caption1").text('');
});
```

I would really appreciate some help on this. Operators are standing by to respond promptly to your input.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not just attaching fancybox to the using the normal manner? You seem to be rewriting the method that fancybox would natively use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was that whit jQuery selector $(".photo_large") you ware selecting all elements whit class="photo_large". ALL of them in the page - even hidden, so that's why when you ware open open another thumbnail from main page you saw old large pix... simple.

You solution was wrong as well, because when you ware closing preview window you selected all elements $(".photo_large") and change their "src:" to nothing!!!

so here's my solution:

Remove:

```
$("#fancybox-close").click(function(){
   $(".photo_large").attr({ src: ''});
   $(".caption1").text('');
});
```

Replace:

```
$(".photo_large").attr({ src: largePath});
$(".caption1").text(caption);
```

With:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().prev().find(".photo_large").attr({ src: largePath});            
$(this).parent().parent().parent().next().find(".caption1").text(caption);
```

Should work, if i count parents right... :) GBY!

Comment: I'm sorry but this is plain nonsense. Why go to the point of loading a jquery plugin if you are then not going to utilize it's methods properly. And parent().parent().parent() ?? Seriously Why not parents(selector) ?? Read the API! This is the problem with jQuery IMO the entry level is far too low so it's too easy to do badly.

Comment: @James: That may be a problem for you, but for people with little JS experience, it is quite the gateway into a fine language. I agree there are right ways and wrong ways to do things, but the wrong ways will sometimes work just fine for some. Instead of posting a rather bitter-sounding comment, why not offer this as an answer and perhaps get some credit for it?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you are targeting all elements with your `.class` selector.  They should be relative to the current `.frame` shown.

```
$("a:has(img.web-port)").click(function() {
    var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
    var caption = $(this).attr("title");
    var $frame = $(this).parents(".frame"); //get the current frame
    var $large = $frame.find(".photo_large"); //find the large photo within that frame
    $large.attr("src", largePath).show();
    $frame.find(".caption1").text(caption);
    return false;
});

$("#fancybox-close").click(function() {
    //Reset everything back to the initial state of the div.
    var $frame = $("#fancybox-content .frame");
    var $a = $frame.find(".thumb1 a").first(); //reset the frame to the first thumb a
    var $large = $frame.find(".photo_large");
    $large.attr("src", $a.attr("href"));
    $frame.find(".caption1").text($a.attr("title"));
});
```

**Example of it working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/JtcTs/1/).**

Comment: Mark. Yes, this option works too. It is a tad more complex than the option above, but worth taking not of. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What if instead of clearing the source, you simply hide the image on closing, and show it again upon opening?

```
$("a:has(img.web-port)").click(function() {
    var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
    var caption = $(this).attr("title");
    $(".photo_large").attr({ src: largePath});
    $(".photo_large").show();  // <---------------------------LOOK HERE
    $(".caption1").text(caption);
    return false;
});

$("#fancybox-close").click(function(){
   $(".photo_large").hide();  // <---------------------------LOOK HERE
   $(".caption1").text('');
});
```

Comment: I added the code and it still does the same thing. Please take a look.

Comment: In looking this over more carefully. Showing the large image is dependent on click the thumbnail. There has to be something that triggers it when the window is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the native fancybox method to do this.

```
<a id="exampleOne" title="title you want to pass" href="path to large image">
    <img alt="exampleOne" src="path to small image">
</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a#exampleOne").fancybox();
});
```

Comment: James. Help me out here. I have 16 entries on that page, not to mention all the thumbnail clicking inside. How would this cover the situation? Thanks.